# Repository structure for different platforms

Tags: github

So I have a desktop application written in Java called XYZ and it is in a GitHub repository called XYZ. Now I have been working on an iOS app with the same name of XYZ. If I want to add this to GitHub now, what do I do? The obvious thing seems to be just adding iOS to the end of the repo name, but I'm not sure of there is some naming convention that other developers use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official naming convention.
You could use XYZ, but include two different builds (for instance two different pom.xml), one for each platform.

If you have sources that differ between platform, you might want to isolate them in their own Git repo, and aggregate them in a common XYZ repo [through submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).
See for instance "[Build multi-platform executable for a SWT application using maven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21351905/6309)".